# Tab Icons NativeScript

Tags: nativescript-vue

I tried to add icons for my TabView with VueJS in NativeScript.
I downloaded a few Icons with size 128x128px as PNG. Afterwards I converted them to have the right scaling with the @3 @2 @1 annotation.

Trying to add them in the code like this:

```
<TabViewItem title="Events" iconSource="res://events">
```

The files are all in Resource Folder under iOS: 
[image]

After reloading and reinstalling the Preview app the Icons still do not show. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it is needed to remove `platform` folder and rebuild the entire project to tns reload the new `res` files

Comment: Thank you! Deleting the platform folder and run 'tns build' afterwards solved it.